# SQL Server view over per-minute performance data and its details

Tags: sql-server

I have these two tables `[PerfData]` and `[ProductionBlocks]`.

`[PerfData]` contains performance of machines in per-minute resolution, so each row contains timestamp, ID of machine and cycle count.

`[ProductionBlocks]` contains aggregated data of production. Each row is one block of continuous production. So it has columns `StartTime`, `EndTime`, `ID` of machine, and some other data that users are setting, for example work order ID, operator name, etc...

For reporting now I need to create a view over `[PerfData]` augmented by data from `[ProductionBlocks]`. I have a simple view that does what I need, but it is pretty slow:

```
SELECT 
    [some columns from PerfData],
    [some columns from ProductionBlocks] 
FROM 
    PerfData 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ProductionBlocks ON PerfData.MachineID = ProductionBlocks.PrimaryMachineID 
                     AND PerfData.PerfTimeStamp BETWEEN ProductionBlocks.BlockStart AND ProductionBlocks.BlockEnd
```

I need the data for reporting purposes of actual performance of machines, now I have a sample with 300'000 rows and it takes 4 minutes to complete.

I think I need completely different solution, but I can imagine nothing but adding indexes to tables, which helps only a little. I tried also index on the view, but there was error saying that view is not bound to the schema, which is something completely new for me.

Can you advise me how to accomplish that better?

Comment: Somewhere between the results of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql-server+performance+slow+how+to+improve+), is the answer you need.  Did you (try to) find it ?

Comment: Also please read: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)  and [FAQ Index for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: I'm seeking for advice how to do it better, not for solution, I can't post both tables here, they are pretty big.  Do you think that create scripts for tables and view would be useful for such question?

Comment: At least the DDL for your tables would help.  Second step might be (current) execution plan.

Comment: You need to create view with schemabinding if you want to index it. Google indexed view sql server for some info. Also, as other said, table script of relevant columns and indexes is usually needed to answer performance questions.

Comment: With regard to indexing the view, check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver16 specifically, schemabinding is a setting which prevents you from modifying the underlying tables used by the view (thus binding the view to the schema). If you are confident those tables won't change, you can enable it. Otherwise, if you later need to change the tables it's a bit more of a process.

Comment: Thank you for links to the MS documentation. I can use google, but mine question is if the index is the good way, if there isn't something way better?